# Incompatible peer dependencies found - upgrading Angular compiler from 8 to 9

Tags: angular

I am following the official document to upgrade.

This step was completed without any errors.

```
ng update @angular/compiler@9
```

The next step failed.

```
The installed Angular CLI version is outdated.
Installing a temporary Angular CLI versioned 9.1.15 to perform the update.
✔ Packages successfully installed.
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 32 dependencies.
Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
                  Package "@angular/compiler-cli" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/compiler" (requires "15.2.4" (extended), 
would install "9.1.13").
× Migration failed: Incompatible peer dependencies found.
Peer dependency warnings when installing dependencies means that those dependencies might not work correctly together.
You can use the '--force' option to ignore incompatible peer dependencies and instead address these warnings later.
  See "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-SMRJqP\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

The dependencies

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.13",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.4",
    "bulma": "^0.7.4",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.14.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.13",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^0.0.28",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^6.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~5.0.2"
  }
}
```

And the ng version

```
Angular CLI: 15.2.4
Node: 18.14.2
Package Manager: npm 9.6.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 15.2.4
... animations, cli, common, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1502.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular   15.2.4
@angular-devkit/core            15.2.4
@angular-devkit/schematics      15.2.4
@angular/compiler               8.2.14
@angular/language-service       8.2.14
@schematics/angular             15.2.4
rxjs                            6.3.3
typescript                      5.0.2
```

Everything is up to date but only the compiler and language-service are out of date, it seems what ever i do they just do update.

I used --force but that didn't help